# $P(X_1 > X_2 + X_3 + 2)$ for a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm doing the next exercise by following the hints of the book but I don't get the final answer:

**Problem:** Let $X=(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ have a multivariate normal distribution with mean vector 0 and variance-covariance matrix:

∑ = $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 1\\  0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $

**Find:** $P(X_1 > X_2 + X_3 + 2)$

**My attempt:**
Let $Z = X_1 - X_2 - X_3$.

Note that $Z=p*X$ where $p= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $x =  \begin{pmatrix} X_1\\ X_2\\X_3 \end{pmatrix} $

Now I do the calculations:

$E(Z)=p*E(X)=0$, given p vector of constants and mean 0 by hypothesis.

$Var(Z)=p*Var(X)*p=7$, with one of the p's like row vector and the other one like column vector.

The initial probability can be rewritten like: $P(X_1-X_2-X_3>2)=P(Z>2)$.

Someone told me a property that is like: $P\left(\frac{Z-mean}{\sqrt{var(Z)}}\right)>\frac{2- mean}{\sqrt{var(Z)}}$ but I'm not sure.

The book gives a **Hint** that is: Find a vector a so that $aX= X_1 - X_2 - X_3$ and use the theorem: [theorem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCBDI.png), but I'm not sure how to use it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

**PD:** sorry for not use very well HTML but I'm learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo: $p$ should be $(1, -1, -1)$, but otherwise I think you've correctly computed the mean and variance of $Z$. I'm a little concerned that you didn't recognize that this is exactly what the hint is telling you to do.

In any case, you've reduced the problem to computing $P(Z > 2)$ when $Z \sim N(0, 7)$. The point of rewriting this as $P(\frac{Z-0}{\sqrt{7}} > \frac{2-0}{\sqrt{7}}$ is because $\frac{Z-0}{\sqrt{7}}$ is standard normal, so you can look up this probability in a normal table (or use a computer).

Comment: Oh, I understood, I'm a little confused with the notation and, for that reason, I don't get if I follow the correct or not the hit, especially about using the theorem, but I get it when you write N(0,7). And yes is a typo, I edit it right now. One other thing, at this time I only study probability theory for that reason I am not very familiar to use tables, how is it? Thank you very much, it was very helpful.

Comment: @Nkm20 Use [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table#Complementary_cumulative) for example. Since $2/\sqrt{7} \approx 0.76$, look at the row for $0.7$ and the column for $+0.06$.